# Risks of riding E-bike under high voltage power lines

Tags: ac, dc, high-voltage, three-phase

I've recently experienced a small electric shock each time while I was passing under international power lines for 3 times. They transport at around 330K volts.
While it didn't hit me really hard, a few questions came to my mind:

1. Is there any influence of the battery or motor on power level of such shock? If so, how specs affect it.
2. What is the influence of the weather conditions (fog, rain) in this case.
3. How serious it can get with lower altitude to the lines (on mountain terrain etc) and higher voltage (400-500 kV).

Comment: "They transport at around 330K volts" - AC or DC? Where are they located?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Above the ground in the air. DC tag is for the bike.

Comment: How high were they above you?

Comment: @BruceAbbott At least 10m. But it really varied due to mountain terrain.

Comment: Reverse placebo effect.

Comment: Risks of riding an E-bike under HV lines is approximately identical to riding a regular bike under HV lines. With the exception that the E-bike has potential risk of running out of batteries, which might cause some tension.

Comment: @Justme +1 for causing "some *tension*".

Comment: @Andyaka https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2655190/Cyclist-told-grab-metal-bike-time-rides-overhead-power-line-gives-ELECTRIC-SHOCK.html I guess not. But here's what I can do: I can get there again and take multimeter with me. And then use it to check the values.

Comment: NCV detector is indicating high level of electric field near the ground, 4/4, but that's as high as the level goes https://ibb.co/cwrRB03